# Como corrigir o erro "EPROTO" depois de atualizar a versão do Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, request, https

O seguinte código funciona na versão `v10.15.3`:

```
const { post } = require('request');

post({
  url: 'https://cidadao.sinesp.gov.br/sinesp-cidadao/mobile/consultar-placa/v4',
  body: '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n<v:Envelope xmlns:v=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n  <v:Header>\n    <b>LGE Nexus 5</b>\n    <c>ANDROID</c>\n    <d>v4</d>\n    <e>4.3.2</e>\n    <f>98.193.54.223</f>\n    <g>514650d8dba4784ed08b5a029583576361a50bc5</g>\n    <h>-3272.3179572637086</h>\n    <i>940.839492700698</i>\n    <j/>\n    <k/>\n    <l>2019-05-24 10:24:35</l>\n    <m>8797e74f0d6eb7b1ff3dc114d4aa12d3</m>\n  </v:Header>\n  <v:Body xmlns:n0=\"http://soap.ws.placa.service.sinesp.serpro.gov.br/\">\n    <n0:getStatus>\n      <a>LSU3J43</a>\n    </n0:getStatus>\n  </v:Body>\n</v:Envelope>',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'User-Agent': 'SinespCidadao / 3.0.2.1 CFNetwork / 758.2.8 Darwin / 15.0.0',
    Host: 'cidadao.sinesp.gov.br'
  },
}, (err, httpResponse, body) => {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(httpResponse));
});
```

Mas após atualizar para a `v12.2.0` ou acima tenho o seguinte erro:

> ```
> Error: write EPROTO 17432:error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\statem\statem_lib.c:1922:
>
>     at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:83:16) {
>   errno: 'EPROTO',
>   code: 'EPROTO',
>   syscall: 'write'
> }
> ```

Como posso corrigir o problema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro indicado é o `unsupported protocol` ou `protocolo não suportado`. Provavelmente o certificado do endereço `cidadao.sinesp.gov.br` é assinado com `TLSv1.0` e partir da versão `v11.4.0` do `Node.js` a versão mínima suportada do protocolo é `TLSv1.2`. Então para que a chamada para este endereço funcione nas versões posteriores é necessário iniciar o `Node.js` com a flag [`--tls-min-v1.0`](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_default_min_version).

Comment: Perfeito a resposta eu só adicionaria que é possível mudar essa configuração através da variável de ambiente `NODE_OPTIONS=--tls-min-v1.0` no caso de usar AWS Lamba ou https://vercel.com/ por exemplo